# Skull Collecting

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I'm about to start replaying levels to get the collectibles, both skulls and intel tapes, and was wondering if after collecting one of either type, will I need to complete the level for it to register?

Or can I go back to the level select right after I have collected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mission **does not** have to be completed for a collected skull to register.

A mission can be aborted immediately after collecting a skull and it will appear in the active skull list on the level select.